# How to validate "minBufferTime" in DASH mpd?

Tags: mpeg, mpeg-4, mpeg-dash

From std `MPEG_DASH_c057623_ISO_IEC_23009-1_2012` spec, came to know as follows

The client buffers media of for at least value of `@minBufferTime` attribute duration before starting the presentation.
Specifies a common duration used in the definition of the Representation data rate.

Consider a hypothetical constant bitrate channel of bandwidth with the value of this attribute in bits per second (bps). Then, if the Representation is continuously delivered at this bitrate, starting at any SAP that is indicated either by `@startWithSAP` or by any Segment Index box, a client can be assured of having enough data for continuous playout providing playout begins after `@minBufferTime * @bandwidth` bits have been received (i.e. at time `@minBufferTime` after the first bit is received).

Guys I am unable to understand how we can cross verify "`minBufferTime`" value. From my understanding, i guess its related to segmentation duration. I am not sure.

Please give your input. It helps a lot.

Comment: How to validate “bandwidth” also in same DASH mpd?

Answer (score 1):

My answer might be a bit late but you might want to have a look at my [calculation](https://github.com/castlabs/dashencrypt/blob/master/dash.fragmencrypter/src/main/java/com/castlabs/dash/dashfragmenter/mp4todash/AbstractManifestWriter.java#L76).

Basically I remove size(sample) bytes from the buffer while I'm filling the buffer with (bandwidth/8)*duration(sample). After each sample I check if a new minimum has been reach. This minimum is in bytes and needs to be converted in seconds by dividing it by the bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

just use seconds for the minBufferTime

Examples can be found here: 
http://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/2012/02/01/dash-support/
http://www-itec.aau.at/dash/